# python-'str' abject has no attribute 'scatter'

Tags: string, python-3.x, matplotlib, scatter-plot, subplot

I need to plot a 7x7 scatterplot diagram by metplotlib.pyplot (no seaborn at this moment). I try to make it semi automatics, so I use an array of ax names ax11, ax12, ......, ax77 to present the subplots. mean while when I use them to call scatter, it is rejected, I think python recognize them as strings but not keywords for the subplot. The Error Message is "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'scatter'". Here is the part of the code:

---

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

characters = ['A','B','C','D','E','F']

box = dict(facecolor ='yellow', pad = 5, alpha = 0.2)

fig, ((ax11,ax12,ax13,ax14,ax15,ax16,ax17),\
      (ax21,ax22,ax23,ax24,ax25,ax26,ax27),\
      (ax31,ax32,ax33,ax34,ax35,ax36,ax37),\
      (ax41,ax42,ax43,ax44,ax45,ax46,ax47),\
      (ax51,ax52,ax53,ax54,ax55,ax56,ax57),\
      (ax61,ax62,ax63,ax64,ax65,ax66,ax67),\
      (ax71,ax72,ax73,ax74,ax75,ax76,ax77),\
      ) = plt.subplots(7,7)
fig.subplots_adjust(left = 0.2, wspace =0.2,)
fig.tight_layout(pad=1, w_pad=2, h_pad=4.0)
st = fig.suptitle("Scatterplot diagram", \
     fontsize="x-      large")

for i in range(7):
    for j in range(7):
        no_ax = str(i)+str(j)
        nm_ax = "ax"+str(no_ax)
        nm_ax.scatter(data[caracters[i]],data[caracters[i]])
        nm_ax.set_title('xy')
        nm_ax.set_xlabel('x')
        nm_ax.set_ylabel('y')
        continue 

st.set_y(0.95)
fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.85)

plt.show()
```

---

I believe there is a method to convert the string to a right format, but I do not know how. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to achieve with this code. The main reason is that noone knows what `data` is. You need to provide that information, and better directly include `data` in your code. Use a simplified version which allows to reproduce the error.

Comment: It might not have anything to do with the data type. The problem is that when usually use ax1.scatter([1,2,3],[1,2,3]), but here I use 'ax11'.scatter([1,2,3],[1,2,3]). the string 'ax11' needs to be converted to the same type as ax1. This is the way how Python goes, I guess.

Comment: its nothing to do with the data type. As you say above, `"ax"+str(no_ax)` is a python string, but you need the `Axes` instance to call `scatter` from. There are many ways to loop over those axes instances; take a look at the `matplotlib` examples to see some. For example, http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplots_demo.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general the approach of building variable names from strings should be avoided. While this can be done using the `eval` function, it's not even necessary.

The problem lies in the lines

```
no_ax = str(i)+str(j) #this is a string
nm_ax = "ax"+str(no_ax) # this is still a string
nm_ax.scatter(data[caracters[i]],data[caracters[i]]) 
# a string cannot be plotted to
```

A string does not have a `scatter` method. What you need is the `axes` object to which you plot.

A solution is to just use the axes that are created in the call to `plt.subplots()`directly in the loop.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=7,nrows=7)

for i in range(7):
    for j in range(7):
        axes[i,j].scatter(np.random.rand(5),np.random.rand(5))
        axes[i,j].set_title('{},{}'.format(i,j))

plt.show()
```